# how to gather columns which are numbered sequentially with tidyr

Tags: r, tidyr

I have a set of columns as follows

```
rowid   TimePoint2   TimePoint3    TimePoint4     TimePoint5    TimePoint6
```

I want to tidy the data but the gather function doesn't recognise the column names when I use he paste function
What I want is

```
rowid
1   TimePoint2    43
2   TimePoint3    34
3   TimePoint4    24
4   TimePoint5    22
5   TimePoint6    44
```

etc

My code:

so instead of writing:

```
y="TimePoint"
  Mydf<-
    select(df,matches(y),rowid)%>%
    gather(variable, value, TimePoint1,TimePoint2,TimePoint3,TimePoint4,TimePoint5,TimePoint6)
```

I want to write something like:

```
y="TimePoint"
  Mydf<-
    select(df,matches(y),rowid)%>%
    gather(variable, value, paste(y,1:10,",",sep=""))
```

The error I get with the above is `Error: All select() inputs must resp;ve to integer column positions. The following do not: * paste (y,1:10,",",sep="")`

Comment: I think you can use `starts_with` from **dplyr**, as you would in `select()`.

Comment: OK great. Please add as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can do:

```
Mydf <- select(df,matches(y),rowid)%>%
    gather(variable, value, starts_with("TimePoint"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are selecting the columns that matches "TimePoint", this will also work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
y <- "TimePoint"
Mydf <- df %>% select(rowid,matches(y)) %>% 
               gather(variable,value,-1)
print(Mydf)
##  rowid   variable value
##1     1 TimePoint2    43
##2     1 TimePoint3    34
##3     1 TimePoint4    24
##4     1 TimePoint5    22
##5     1 TimePoint6    44
```

Here, we `select` as you do but put the `rowid` column first. Then gather all columns except first one using `-1`.

**Data:**

```
df <- structure(list(rowid = 1L, TimePoint2 = 43L, TimePoint3 = 34L, 
    TimePoint4 = 24L, TimePoint5 = 22L, TimePoint6 = 44L), .Names = c("rowid", 
"TimePoint2", "TimePoint3", "TimePoint4", "TimePoint5", "TimePoint6"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -1L))
##  rowid TimePoint2 TimePoint3 TimePoint4 TimePoint5 TimePoint6
##1     1         43         34         24         22         44
```